# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/net/http/HttpRequest;

Tags: java, android, httprequest, noclassdeffounderror, ip2location

I want to use IP2Location.io in my Android Studio app. I am starting with this program from their internet site. I am stuck on this error.  I do not understand why this difficulty including java/net/http/HttpRequest. I researched many similar threads on Stackoverflow but did not find a resolution. I tried unsuccessfully to include other HttpRequest. Perhaps
I do not know how to do that. Any ideas will be appreciated.

I started at... https://blog.ip2location.com/knowledge-base/using-ip2location-io-java-sdk-in-a-maven-project/
**Using IP2Location.io Java SDK in a Maven project**

I scrolled down to...
**Adding the IP2Location.io Java SDK into the Maven dependency**

I worked thru to the end, adding the code to a new Android Studio "Empty Activity". I made changes as I went along to get rid of the "red errors" :)
It took me most of a day. My last, most difficult error was the infamous red R. The program builds cleanly on Android studio. But here is the result..

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: gmd.com.mickwebsite.ip2locationion, PID: 1505
**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/net/http/HttpRequest;**
    at com.ip2location.IPGeolocation.Lookup(IPGeolocation.java:59)
    at com.ip2location.IPGeolocation.Lookup(IPGeolocation.java:46)
    at gmd.com.mickwebsite.ip2locationion.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
```

...
**Here is the complete code...**
**Note this about half way: // <<--App hangs up here**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.ip2location.Configuration;
import com.ip2location.DomainWhois;
import com.ip2location.IPGeolocation;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView mainDisplay = findViewById(R.id.mainDisplay);

        // Configures IP2Location.io API key
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
//      String apiKey = "API KEY";  //  I used my personal API key
        config.setApiKey(apiKey);
        IPGeolocation ipl = new IPGeolocation(config);
        // Lookup ip address geolocation data

        JsonObject myObj;
        // the language parameter is only available for Plus and Security plans
        try {
            myObj = ipl.Lookup("8.8.8.8");  **// <<--App hangs up here**
            // java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
            // Failed resolution of: Ljava/net/http/HttpRequest;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mainDisplay.setText(String.valueOf(e));
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        mainDisplay.setText(String.valueOf(myObj));
// I added the id for the textView in the xml
        DomainWhois whois = new DomainWhois(config);
        // Lookup domain information
        JsonObject myObj2;
        try {
            myObj2 = whois.Lookup("locaproxy.com");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mainDisplay.setText(String.valueOf(e));
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        mainDisplay.setText(String.valueOf(myObj2));
    }   //  protected void onCreate
}   // public class MainActivity
```

Comment: That blog post is for desktop or server Java, not Android.

Comment: Thank you. I know that. I have been hoping that it might be workable on Android. Is that a hopeless hope? :)

Comment: In this case, most likely yes. Do they have an Android-specific SDK?

Comment: I am now looking at using the IP2LOCATION DB3 data base, starting with the free edition to see if I can get it to work.
I need to be able to load the DB3 into a data base in my app. The problem is that I have no experience with database programming so it is another big, technical learning experience.
 I am looking for an example that has a format similar to DB3 [several columns of data, retrieval only] so that I can get going on it. Have not found one yet. I'll keep digging. Thank you again :)